# Applescript returns "The command exited with a non-zero status" on do shell script

Tags: applescript

I'm working with an Applescript that I'm trying to make, after it does a command to check back results of a command, but when I execute it, it prompts a message (in AppleScript Editor); `Expected expression but found “error”.`.

How can I fallback and check if the command is same as `The command exited with a non-zero status.` so I can do something else if it's the same as the error message?

```
do shell script "echo \"stats\" | nc localhost 11211" password "~password~" with administrator privileges

if error = "The command exited with a non-zero status." then
    display dialog "Returned zero"
else if result = "The command exited with a non-zero status." then
    display dialog "Returned zero"
else if result = "" then
    do shell script "memcached -d -l 127.0.0.1 -p 11211 -m 64"
    display dialog "Memcached Started"
else
    do shell script "killall memcached" with administrator privileges
    display dialog "Memcached Stopped"
end if
```

**EDIT:** Updated version

```
set error to do shell script "echo \"stats\" | nc localhost 11211" password "~password~" with administrator privileges

if error = "The command exited with a non-zero status." then
    do shell script "memcached -d -l 127.0.0.1 -p 11211 -m 64"
    display dialog "Memcached Started"
else
    do shell script "killall memcached" with administrator privileges
    display dialog "Memcached Stopped"
end if
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your particular problem is in using the word "error" as a variable. Error is a special word to applescript so it can't be used as a variable.

However, even if you fix that problem your code still won't work properly. You catch error messages with a try block. Note that "**theError**" contains the error message...

```
try
    do shell script "echo \"stats\" | nc localhost 11211" password "~password~" with administrator privileges
on error theError
    if theError is "The command exited with a non-zero status." then
        do shell script "memcached -d -l 127.0.0.1 -p 11211 -m 64"
        display dialog "Memcached Started"
    else
        do shell script "killall memcached" with administrator privileges
        display dialog "Memcached Stopped"
    end if
end try
```